# C define inplace xor question explanation

Tags: c

This code is given -

```
#define DO_SOMETHING(a, b) a^=b^=a^=b
```

I need to choose one of the options regarding what the code does -

a) turn all the bits in arguments SET

b) calculate distance between two arguments DIFF

c) substitute between two arguments SWAP

d) their is error in the code

e) multiply between two arguments MULT

Answer is suggested to be c. But I don't understand how. Can anyone explain?

EDIT :

I tried to run the code and I get the following output -

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:3:25: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    3 | #define D_(a, b) a^=b^=a^=b
      |                         ^~
main.c:7:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘D_’
    7 |     printf("%d\n", D_(1, 2));
      |                    ^~
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the XOR (^) swap algorithm work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093606/how-does-the-xor-swap-algorithm-work)

Comment: The macro has UB as `a` is modified more that once without a sequence point.

Comment: shouldn't the answer be c, then. because its an error

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [How does the XOR (^) swap algorithm work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093606/how-does-the-xor-swap-algorithm-work) because that question has assignments in separate statements and so is well defined, whereas this question has assignments in a single statement and is not defined by the C standard due to the lack of sequencing.

Comment: Is that "their is error" only in this question? If that is also in the original question then be careful with that teacher and the answer d). Yes, I am a little cynical here, but not directed against OP.

Comment: D_ only works when called on variables, never on constants. Your printf call evaluates to `1^=2^=1^=2` and that's obviously invalid. Use something like this and the macro will do what it's intended to do: `unsigned i = 1; unsigned j = 2; D_(i, j); printf("%u %u\n", i, j);`

Comment: Note also that "clever" code like this is ***REALLY BAD CODE***.  It's hard to understand, and it's actually ***less*** efficient than a swap using a temporary variable.   A swap with a temporary will almost always be implemented like "load `a` into register 1, load `b` into register 2, save register 1 to `b`, save register 2 to `a`".  Now count all the different register loads, register stores, ***and*** the bitwise operations needed to perform an XOR swap...  Yep, the "clever" person who thought an XOR swap was "better" just outsmarted himself.  "Clever" is actually quite dumb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How bitwise XOR operations can swap values is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093606/how-does-the-xor-swap-algorithm-work). However, the behavior of the code shown here is not defined by the C standard because of this rule in C 2018 6.5 2:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

In `a^=b^=a^=b`, the rightmost `a^=b` is a compound assignment. It evaluates the left and right operands (`a` and `b`), XORs them, and produces, as a result for further use in the expression, the value that it will store in `a`. As a *side effect*, it stores that value in `a`.

Then in `b^=a^=b`, this new `^=` takes the value of `b` and `a^=b` (described above), XORs them, and produces the value that it will store in `b`. As a side effect, it stores that value in `b`.

Finally, in `a^=b^=a^=b`, the new `^=` XORs the value of `a` with the value produced above. As a side effect, it stores that value in `a`.

Now we have two side effects that modify `a`. A side effect is something that is done separately from the main evaluation of an expression. The rule quoted above means that multiple side effects should not modify the same object; something should separate them.

An easy way to separate the side effects is to put the assignments in separate statements, because there is a *sequence point* after each expression statement:

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

In addition to sequence points about expression statements, C has other rules about sequencing. For example, one rule for assignment statements is that the side effect of updating the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the operands. So we know that, in `a^=b^=a^=b` the store to `a` occurs after computing the value of `b^=a^=b`. However, the side effect in `a^=b` is not part of the value computation, so we do not know that the side effect in `a^=b^=a^=b` is sequenced after the side effect in `a^=b`. Learning these rules can take a while, as some of them are tricky. For the most part, programmers should avoid them by limiting their use of operations with side effects inside expressions.

### Supplemental Note

Additionally, I realize somebody else wrote the macro you are asking about, but you should know that it is a good practice to enclose macro parameters in parentheses in the macro replacement text:

```
#define DO_SOMETHING(a, b) (a)^=(b)^=(a)^=(b)
```

This is because macros can be called with parameters that are more than simple names, such as expressions with other operators, and those can result in forming an expression with different structure than what the macro author intended. (I think this might not occur in this particular macro since assignment is the lowest precedence operator except for the comma operator, and the comma operator cannot appear unprotected inside a macro parameter since it would be taken as an argument separator. However, using parentheses is good practice nonetheless.)

Comment: In c++, another defect of this code is that if `a` and `b` are references to the same value then it zeros the value.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is
c) substitute between two arguments SWAP

Consider following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DO_SOMETHING(a, b) a^=b^=a^=b
int main() {
    int val1 = 10;
    int val2 = 13;
    printf("%d\n", DO_SOMETHING(val1, val2)); 
    // printf("%d\n", val1 ^= (val2 ^= (val1 ^= val2))); // macro expansion simplified
    printf("val1: %d, val2: %d\n", val1, val2);
  
    return 0;
}
```

This macro uses compound assignment operation while performing XOR and combines the code to swap two values using XOR operation in a single statement
for example two swap two values a and b using XOR operation code is as follows

```
a = a^b;
b = a^b;
a = a^b;
```

now lets expand macro a^=b^=a^=b

```
a^=b^=(a^=b) // a = a^b
a^=(b^=(a^=b)) // b = b^a
a^=(b^=(a^=b)) // a = a^b
```

NOTE: we can not pass literal value to this macro because lvalue is required for assignment so
DO_SOMETHING(3, 5)
will result in compilation error